# Is there a way to end Invoke-WebRequest when response time (not name resolution) longer than x?

Tags: powershell

I want to run a script that checks website response time (not DNS name resolution time) throws an exception when response time is longer than e.g. 60 seconds.

I use `httpstat.us/200?sleep=70000` (i.e. wait for 70 seconds) for testing, but can't find a solution, since `-TimeoutSec` is only checking name resolution time. I don't understand how creating a job or a timer could help in this circumstance.  I tried below code in another forum, which (of course) doesn't work, since it waits for the command to finish. How can I break/interrupt it after 60 seconds?

```bsh
$url = 'httpstat.us/200?sleep=70000'
$Duration = 60

$TimeOut = New-TimeSpan -Seconds $Duration
$Sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
while ($Sw.Elapsed -lt $TimeOut) {
    try {
        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url
    } catch [System.Exception] {
        # Writing the exception in the console
        Write-Host $_.Exception
        exit;
    }
} #EndOf while ($Sw.Elapsed -lt $TimeOut)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-TimeoutSec` does not check DNS resolution time. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-3.0) warns that DNS resolution can take up to 15 seconds to either return a result or time out. Meaning that setting `-TimeoutSec` to a value less than 15 seconds might effectively be extended to 15 because of DNS.

> **`-TimeoutSec`**
>
> Specifies how long the request can be pending before it times out. Enter a value in seconds. The default value, 0, specifies an indefinite time-out.
>
> A Domain Name System (DNS) query can take up to 15 seconds to return or time out. If your request contains a host name that requires resolution, and you set TimeoutSec to a value greater than zero, but less than 15 seconds, it can take 15 seconds or more before a WebException is thrown, and your request times out.

A value of 60 seconds is well beyond that limit, so

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -TimeoutSec $Duration
```

should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason (I assume I used milli seconds for -TimeoutSec) I didn't get it to work before. But now it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you set both `MaxServicePointIdleTime` and the `-TimeOutSec` parameter the requested is aborted after a second in this example:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::MaxServicePointIdleTime = 1000

$url = 'httpstat.us/200?sleep=70000'
$Duration = 60

$TimeOut=New-TimeSpan -Seconds $Duration
$Sw=[Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
While ($Sw.Elapsed -lt $TimeOut)
{
    Try
    {
        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -TimeoutSec 1
    }
    Catch [system.exception]
    {
        # Writing the exception in the console
        Write-Host $_.Exception
        Break
    }
} #EndOf While ($Sw.Elapsed -lt $TimeOut)
```

Comment: Thanks! What's the reason for adding [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::MaxServicePointIdleTime = 1000 ?